# Is there a general formula to calculate the number of specific outcomes in an ordered arrangements?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Calculating the probability that families of 4 children are composed of as many boys as girls.

Assuming here that each birth gives rise to a boy or girl with equiprobability.

***The number of outcomes would be $2^4 = 16$***

By manually calculating the number of outcomes where there are 2 boys and 2 girls we find **$6$ arrangements.**

> Is there a general formula for calculating the number of arrangements where we
>   have 2 boys and 2 girls?

Comment: Yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You can delete this question, or answer it yourself and accept the answer, so that it does not stay on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) solves the problem:

With $n ≥ k ≥ 0$

The general formula is: ${\displaystyle {\binom {n}{k}}={\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}}.}$

In this particular case:

${\displaystyle {\tbinom {4}{2}}={\tfrac {4!}{2!2!}}=6}$

Thanks to @EthanBolke for pointing to the binominal coefficient.